# Woocomerce hide price for specific Category

Tags: php, woocommerce

I would like to hide prices for products in specific categories, prices should be hidden only on shop and category page, but visible on product page, chart and subtotals.

Thank you!

This code has this functionality but I would like to apply it only on specific categories:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'remove_woocommerce_loop_price', 2 );
function remove_woocommerce_loop_price() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the product has a category by `has_term` function, and it's an action hook not a filter

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'remove_woocommerce_loop_price', 2 );
function remove_woocommerce_loop_price() {
    $category_name = 'the_category_name_here';
    if ( has_term( $category_name, 'product_cat' ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the cat name if you have the prodict id with the following:

```
 $term = get_term_by( 'id', $cat_id, 'product_cat' );

 echo $term->name;
```

So simply write a condition to the cat name

```
    function remove_woocommerce_loop_price() {
        if($term->name == 'your_category')
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your solution. I tried to copy it in functions.php and replace it with my category but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the price **based on specific product category slugs**, you can use this:

```
// hide the price based on product categories
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'hide_price_for_specific_product_categories');
function hide_price_for_specific_product_categories() {

    // set the slugs of the product categories for which prices must be hidden
    $categories = array(
        'clothing',
        'bags',
        'shoes'
    );

    global $product;
    // if the product belongs to at least one product category present in the "$categories" array, it hides the price
    if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
    }

}
```

To hide the price **based on specific product category ids**, you can use this:

```
// hide the price based on product categories
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'hide_price_for_specific_product_categories');
function hide_price_for_specific_product_categories() {

    // set the ids of the product categories for which prices must be hidden
    $categories = array( 61 );

    global $product;
    // if the product belongs to at least one product category present in the "$categories" array, it hides the price
    if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
    }

}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your theme's functions.php.*

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your solution. It is working for shop and category page as I rote I need, but I also needed to remove prices on any catalogue page, for exaple also where I created products overview with woocomerece shortcodes.